# sql statement is not functioning properly

Tags: sql, datagrid, vb6, ado, recordset

I have written an `sql` statement which allows me to remove students from the `Datagrid`. I want to alter this so it changes all the values except two fields to 0, when I tried to do it it gives me this error:

> Synatx error in UPDATE statement.

This is the orginal code:
`sql = "update Table1 set [Active] = 'No' where ID =" & SID`

This is what i modified it to:
`sql = "update Table1 set [Mark 1 ENG], [Mark 2 ENG] {removed the others so it does not get clustered} = '0' where ID =" & SID`

```
If YNResponse = vbYes Then
    sql = "update Table1 set [Mark 1 ENG], [Mark 2 ENG] = '0' where ID =" & SID  'find the student and delete them
If CurrentCon.State = adStateOpen Then              
    CurrentCon.Close
End If
    CurrentCon.Open
    CurrentCon.Execute sql
    Adodc1.ConnectionString = Conn.connstr
    Adodc1.CommandType = adCmdText
    Set StudentTable.DataSource = Adodc1
    CurrentCon.Close
    CurrentCon.Open
    Adodc1.Refresh
    frmStudents.Adodc1.Recordset.Sort = "[ID] "
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the issue

```
sql = "update Table1 set [Mark 1 ENG], [Mark 2 ENG] = '0' where ID =" & SID  'find the student and delete the
```

where should be

```
update table1 set [Mark 1 ENG] = 0, [Mark 2 ENG] = 0
```